# Pro-Israel lawmakers in the U.S

Tags: united-states, israel

Are most U.S. politicians pro-Israel? If so, why?

Comment: It's a tricky question about sionism... Do you know anything about it ?

Comment: @GautierC nope.

Comment: Ok. If noone answers before 5pm I'll anwser it, will be a loooooong post.

Comment: @user4012 for sure related but the question is more precise here.

Comment: @user4012 the problem with the other phrasing is that it's intended more to argue a point than as a sincere question.

Comment: @Guest - the general SE policy is that a question is a duplicate if an answer to another question fully addresses the first question. The questions themselves Do NOT need to be identical.

Answer (score 3):

A large number of US politicians are probably pro-Israel in some sense because a significant number of US voters are either sympathetic to the situation of citizens of Israel or have friends or relatives there. Generally politicians tend to be pro-something if a larger minority of voters are firmly pro-something than any firmly opposing number of voters.

There are other reasons why US politicians and voters might wish to support Israel in some way

- Israel is, like the US, a democracy.
- Israel is a friend of the US in a region of the world that contains nations that are somewhat hostile to the US (e.g. Iran) or who are friendly to nations that are somewhat hostile to the US (e.g. Syria is friends with Russia).

Many US politicians and voters also have some sympathy for the situation of the 21% of Israel's population who are Arab. Their support for Arab politicians in Israel's Palestinian territories has a couple of obstacles:

- Fatah had a history of terrorism. Including against US voters.
- Hamas have aims that conflict with the interests of US voters.

Note: When writing about this, there is no avoiding some terms that are controversial: Israel, Palestine, Israeli, Palestinian, Arab. I am using these terms in what I hope is a neutral way - but you can't please all the people all the time.

Comment: don't forget to explain the sionism of the Evangelist, which represents 40millions of people in US !

Comment: It might not be politically correct to mention it, and some might exaggerate it and form crazy conspiracy theories based on it, but it is still a fact: Israel's media presence and therefore lobbying power is much stronger than of other countries.

Comment: @vsz are we here to do "politically" correct speech ? I think it is a reality (as a lobby) , let's not say it's a conspiration, just a big lobby.

Comment: @GautierC : I mentioned it because there are people who cry "Nazi" for even the slightest mention of a possibility of a Jewish lobby.

Comment: @GautierC Half-correct. We are here to answer questions. We are not here to discuss. I think RedGrittyBrick's neutral language is very appropriate when one wants to inform people on a controversial topic like this.

Comment: The difference is between saying a "Jewish lobby" and an "Israeli lobby." One is a political entity and one is a religion.